# Horizontal calendar view with TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

any way to display calendar with TabLayout ?

Like this one:

[image: Horizontal calendar view]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your research effort also. 
Please refer this Library :
 [Horizontal calender](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5087)
It describes the implementation procedures also